# execute Oracle stored procedure using MyBatis/Spring and parse results to a POJO

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm trying to execute an Oracle stored procedure, and map the results to a POJO, with mybatis/spring using annotations (i.e. not XML). The inputs/outputs for the stored procedure are:

```
P_INPUT     VARCHAR2         IN                         
P_OUTPUT    VARCHAR2         OUT            
P_COUNT     BINARY_INTEGER   OUT
```

And the POJO looks like this:

```
public class MyRecord {
    private String output;
    private Integer count;
    // getters and setters...
}
```

The snippet in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37491317/2626491), which says it's for Oracle, worked perfectly for me against a MySQL stored procedure. However, when I tried to execute the following against an Oracle stored procedure:

```
@Select(value= "{ CALL my_user.some_package.my_proc('${input}') }")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
@ResultType(MyRecord.class)
@Results({
                @Result(property="output", column="P_OUTPUT"),
                @Result(property="count", column="P_COUNT"),
         })
MyRecord parseMyInput(@Param("input") String input);
```

... it threw the following error:

```
bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'my_proc'
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

From the error message, it sounds like the string being passed to the function may be incompatible with Oracle's `VARCHAR2`, or I'm somehow sending more than one argument. The string that I'm passing to the function, incidentally, is `(12345)`.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It is an Oracle procedure so, you have to pass those out parameters too. It works as reference. It would be something like: `{ CALL my_user.some_package.my_proc('${input}', '${out1}', '${out2}') }` But I have no Idea how to do it on the MyBatis annotations.

Comment: Maybe this would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215784/java-mybatis-stored-procedure-call-with-out-parameters

Comment: Another one that even makes your question duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910795/mybatis-annotations-to-call-stored-procedure-and-get-out-params

Comment: Thanks so much, @JorgeCampos. The answer in the duplicate question didn't work for me, but I'm trying your other suggestions right now.

Comment: Have you tested passing the parameters as in the duplicate question? It would be something like: `{ CALL my_user.some_package.my_proc('${input, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR}', '${out1, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR}', '${out2, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER }')`

Comment: I'm trying it now, @Jorge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jorge was right. It was necessary to instantiate the POJO with the input parameter:

```
public class MyRecord {
    private String input;
    private String output;
    private Integer count;
    // getters and setters...
}
```

Then set the input parameter of the POJO and call the service:

```
    MyRecord myRecord = new myRecord();
    myRecord.setInput("myInput");

    dbMapperOracle.parseMyInput(myRecord);
```

The service calls the mapper, passing the POJO which contains variables for both the input (which has been set) and output parameters (which are null at this point):

```
public class DbServiceOracle {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSourceOracle")
    private DbMapperOracle dbMapperOracle;

    public MyRecord parseMyInput(MyRecord params){
        dbMapperOracle.parseMyInput(params);
        return params;
    }
}
```

And the mapper maps the results returned from the stored procedure to the POJO:

```
@Select(value= "{ CALL my_user.some_package.my_proc(" +
        "#{input,   mode=IN,  javaType = java.lang.String,  jdbcType=VARCHAR}, " +
        "#{output,  mode=OUT, javaType = java.lang.String,  jdbcType=VARCHAR}, " +
        "#{count,   mode=OUT, javaType = java.lang.Integer, jdbcType=NUMERIC}, "
        ") }")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
@ResultType(MyRecord.class)
@Results({
                @Result(property="input", column="P_INPUT"),
                @Result(property="output", column="P_OUTPUT"),
                @Result(property="count", column="P_COUNT"),
        })
MyRecord parseMyInput(MyRecord params);
```

Credit to Sanjay Kumar, who put [a more complete example](https://github.com/ersanjayverma/spring-mybatis-oracle-storedproc) in his GitHub account.